# Excel VBA 7.1 Error '430': on Set X = New WorkSheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving this error

> Run-time error '430': Class does not support automation or does not
>   support expected interface.

On this line of code.

```
Set GetSheetByName = New Worksheet
```

I have changed it to Set GetSheetByName = Nothing. However I receive Error '91' right after

```
GetSheetByName.Name = "GetSheetByName::Default"
```

There are no missing references from what I can tell. These are the references I have included. If you need anymore information please let me know.

[image: References]

Comment: What do references have to do with a `Worksheet`? A new worksheet can be created by using `Worksheets.Add`.

Comment: Still new to Excel's Macros. Just trying to get as much information out there as possible.

Comment: A worksheet has to exist in a workbook. Which is why you need to use `Worksheets.Add`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `New` up or otherwise own a `Worksheet` object: like `Workbook` objects, these are for Excel to create, manage, and destroy.

The only way to create a worksheet is through Excel's object model, using the `Worksheets.Add` factory method that creates them for you - you can get a `Worksheets` collection object off any `Workbook`, including the `ThisWorkbook` (the VBA project's own host document) and `ActiveWorkbook`:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = SomeWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
```